# What might cause intermittent error in finding the lowest value in a C++ int array?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

I have read several answers related to "How to find the lowest value in an array". It seems simple, but on implementing it I am seeing errors roughly 10% of the time, where the index identified as having the lowest value does not have the lowest.

The variable m_siaValue[6][4] is a two-dimensional array of short ints, with all positions populated with random values between 1 and 6. The first dimension contains 6 rows (indexes 0-5), and the second dimension identifies 4 columns (indexes 0-3).

The variable m_siaIndexOfLowest[6] is an array of short ints corresponding by index to the rows in m_siaValue[6][4] array. The values of this array are intended to hold the index of the lowest value cell (column) in each row of m_siaValue.

It seems so short and simple that I am perplexed it fails. But moreso that it only fails 10% of the time. Can anyone see what might be wrong?

```
for (short siX= 0;siX < 6; siX++) {

    // Assign cell/column 0 as lowest. Then loop through the other 3,
    // comparing and reassigning if other cells are lower.
    m_siaIndexOfLowest[siX] = 0;
    for (short siY = 1;siY < 4; siY++) {
        if (m_siaValue[siX][siY] < m_siaValue[siX][siY-1]) { 
            m_siaIndexOfLowest[siX] = siY;
        }
    }
}
```

Output showing error. Total is calculated immediately after this code, before any display or movement of data by subtracting the identified lowest value from the sum of the row. So, the total confirms the error is in identifying the lowest, rather than in placing or coloring cells.
[image]

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: An even better tool than a debugger: write down `3 2 4 3` and execute your algorithm by hand: "Is 2 less than 3? It is, so discard the old index and keep 1. Is 4 less than 2? No, so keep the 1. Is 3 less than 4? It is, so discard the old index and keep 3. We've reached the end, so 3 is the index of the smallest element. WTF?!"

Answer (score 2):

The logic used in the following block is wrong. You are always comparing two adjacent elements. That does not give you the lowest value.

```
for (short siY = 1;siY < 4; siY++) {
    if (m_siaValue[siX][siY] < m_siaValue[siX][siY-1]) { 
        m_siaIndexOfLowest[siX] = siY;
    }
}
```

I suggest something along the lines of:

```
short indexOfLowest = 0;
auto lowest = m_siaValue[siX][0];
for (short siY = 1;siY < 4; siY++) {
   if (m_siaValue[siX][siY] < lowest ) { 
      lowest = m_siaValue[siX][siY];
      indexOfLowest = siY;
   }
}
m_siaIndexOfLowest[siX] = indexOfLowest;
```